# Used named curve in signing request with OpenSSL?

Tags: openssl

I am using openssl 1.0.1e and attempting to generate a CSR. In this case we are generating our own key pair and will sign independently, so I can't have openssl generate the key pair and then sign for me. This is all within an embedded device, so making the calls to the x509_req.
I have the public key I want to set within the CSR. The private key will not be embedded within the CSR. At this stage I have not called the code to sign this CSR, I have been generating CSRs, then dumping to a file to parse with the openssl req command to test if I am getting this correct.

I setup the x509_req structure with the new, populated with the subject via X509_NAME_add_entry_by_txt, then using X509_REQ_set_subject_name.
The problem is when I try to setup the public key. I know I need to use the X509_REQ_set_pubkey, which takes the req pointer and the evp key pointer, but the issue I am having is finding what items to set for the Evp key.

From what I found I need to create an ec key, set the group, point then ultimately call EVP_PKEY_assign_EC_KEY.
Below is my call stack. Using this, I get a lot of extra information in the CSR that is not needed, below the call stack. I think the "extra" data is actually incorrect and I do not need it as part of the CSR. Is there a way I can just cut off this extra data? (Remember in code so no command line interaction). I wonder if I am doing something overly complicated, the key pair is a ECC SHA384 and the public key is 96 bytes.

I thank you for any help on this!

***Call stack for populating evp key (removing if's and other checking...but it is there)***

*ec_key_ptr_ptr = EC_KEY_new()

ec_group_ptr = EC_GROUP_new_by_curve_name(NID_secp384r1)

ec_point_ptr = EC_POINT_new(ec_group_ptr)

EC_KEY_set_group(*ec_key_ptr_ptr, ec_group_ptr)

EC_POINT_oct2point(ec_group_ptr,
                   ec_point_ptr,
                   public_key_ptr, /*This is the public key I want to set*/
                   public_key_len,
                   NULL)

EC_KEY_set_public_key(*ec_key_ptr_ptr, ec_point_ptr)

*evp_key_ptr_ptr = EVP_PKEY_new()

EVP_PKEY_assign_EC_KEY(*evp_key_ptr_ptr, *ec_key_ptr_ptr)

****Extra items in the CSR that I do not want/need****

```
           Field Type: prime-field
           Prime:
               00:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:
               ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:
               ff:ff:fe:ff:ff:ff:ff:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:
               ff:ff:ff:ff
           A:

               00:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:
               ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:
               ff:ff:fe:ff:ff:ff:ff:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:
               ff:ff:ff:fc
           B:
               00:b3:31:2f:a7:e2:3e:e7:e4:98:8e:05:6b:e3:f8:
               2d:19:18:1d:9c:6e:fe:81:41:12:03:14:08:8f:50:
               13:87:5a:c6:56:39:8d:8a:2e:d1:9d:2a:85:c8:ed:
               d3:ec:2a:ef
           Generator (uncompressed):
               04:aa:87:ca:22:be:8b:05:37:8e:b1:c7:1e:f3:20:
               ad:74:6e:1d:3b:62:8b:a7:9b:98:59:f7:41:e0:82:
               54:2a:38:55:02:f2:5d:bf:55:29:6c:3a:54:5e:38:
               72:76:0a:b7:36:17:de:4a:96:26:2c:6f:5d:9e:98:
               bf:92:92:dc:29:f8:f4:1d:bd:28:9a:14:7c:e9:da:
               31:13:b5:f0:b8:c0:0a:60:b1:ce:1d:7e:81:9d:7a:
               43:1d:7c:90:ea:0e:5f
           Order:
               00:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:
               ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:c7:63:4d:81:f4:
               37:2d:df:58:1a:0d:b2:48:b0:a7:7a:ec:ec:19:6a:
               cc:c5:29:73
           Cofactor:  1 (0x1)
           Seed:
               a3:35:92:6a:a3:19:a2:7a:1d:00:89:6a:67:73:a4:
               82:7a:cd:ac:73
```

Comment: I actually got this resolved. I had to do this:
"You need to set the EC_KEY to use the named curve option which isn't the 
default. You can do that with: 

EC_KEY_set_asn1_flag(eckey, OPENSSL_EC_NAMED_CURVE);"

Thank you to Dr Stephen N. Henson. OpenSSL project core developer, whom provided this information to me!!!